# Get a percentage of randomly chosen lines from a text file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file (bigfile.txt) with thousands of rows. I want to make a smaller text file with 1 % of the rows which are randomly chosen. I tried the following

```
output=$(wc -l bigfile.txt)
ds1=$(0.01*output)
sort -r bigfile.txt|shuf|head -n ds1
```

It give the following error:
head: invalid number of lines: ‘ds1’

I don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even after you fix your issues with your `bash` script, it cannot do floating point arithmetic. You need external tools like `Awk` which I would use as

```
randomCount=$(awk 'END{print int((NR==0)?0:(NR/100))}' bigfile.txt)
(( randomCount )) && sort -r file | shuf | head -n "$randomCount"
```

E.g. Writing a file with with 221 lines using the below loop and trying to get random lines,

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/abc-script.XXXXXX)
for i in {1..221}; do echo $i; done >> "$tmpfile"
randomCount=$(awk 'END{print int((NR==0)?0:(NR/100))}' "$tmpfile")
```

If I print the count, it would return me a integer number 2 and using that on the next command,

```
sort -r "$tmpfile" | shuf | head -n "$randomCount"
86
126
```

Answer (score 4):

Roll a die (with `rand()`) for each line of the file and get a number between `0` and `1`. Print the line if the die shows less than `0.01`:

```
awk 'rand()<0.01' bigFile
```

Quick test - generate 100,000,000 lines and count how many get through:

```
seq 1 100000000 | awk 'rand()<0.01' | wc -l
999308
```

Pretty close to 1%.

---

If you want the order random as well as the selection, you can pass this through `shuf` afterwards:

```
seq 1 100000000 | awk 'rand()<0.01' | shuf
```

---

On the subject of efficiency which came up in the comments, this solution takes 24s on my iMac with 100,000,000 lines:

```
time { seq 1 100000000 | awk 'rand()<0.01' > /dev/null; }

real    0m23.738s
user    0m31.787s
sys     0m0.490s
```

The only other solution that works here, heavily based on OP's original code, takes 13 minutes 19s.

Comment: A downvote's a bit harsh for a spelling mistake! Corrected.

Comment: I did downvote, but for the imprecise maths rather than for the spelling mistake - sorry if the comment misled you.  That said, you could combine aspects of your answer and the others - over-estimate the percentage, and then `shuf | head` the result.  That has the advantage of being much more efficient than shuffling the entire output.

Comment: @TobySpeight I don't shuffle the entire output, or pass over the file twice so it is already extremely efficient. In fact I don't shuffle the lines at all because the OP doesn't require the order to be random, only the selection. Furthermore, the maths is not imprecise - a 0.06% is very unlikely to be significant when the OP already stated he had a large number of lines and probably chose to sample and test around 1% of his data, when he could just as easily have chosen 0.5% or 2%.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: `++` for the timing results, actually it is not _my_solution though. I would probably thought of a different logic, I just tried to re-use OP's attempts as close as possible

Comment: @Inian Consider yourself exonerated ;-) I have updated it to remove your name.